# Zoho Creator making a custom function for a report

Tags: scripting, custom-action, zoho

Trying to wrap my head around zoho creator, its not as simple as they make it out to be for building apps… I have an inventory database, and i have four fields that I call to fill a field called Inventory Number (Inv_Num1) –

First Name (First_Name)

Last Name (Last_Name)

Year (Year)

Number (Number)

I have a Custom Function script that I call through a Custom Action in the form report. What I am trying to do is upload a CSV file with 900 entries. Of course, not all of those have those values (first/last/number) so I need to bulk edit all of them. However when I do the bulk edit, the Inv_Num1 field is not updated with the new values. I use the custom action to populate the Inv_Num1 field with the values of the other 4 fields.

Heres is  my script:

```
void onetime.UpdateInv()
{
    for each Inventory_Record in Management
    {
        FN = Inventory_Record.First_Name.subString(0,1);
        LN = Inventory_Record.Last_Name.subString(0,1);
        YR = Inventory_Record.Year.subString(2,4);
        NO = Inventory_Record.Number;
        outputstr = FN + LN + YR + NO;
        Inventory_Record.Inv_Num1 = outputstr;
    }
}
```

I get this error back when I try to run this function

```
Error.
    Error in executing UpdateInv workflow.
        Error in executing For Each Record task.
            Error in executing Set Variable task. Unable to update template variable FN.
                Error evaluating STRING expression :
```

Even though there is a First Name for example, it still thinks there is none. This only happens on the fields I changed with Bulk Edit. If I do each one by hand, then the custom action works—but of course then the Inv_Num1 is already updated through my edit on success functions and makes the whole thing moot.

Answer (score 1):

this may be one year late, you might have found the solution but just to highlight, the error u were facing was just due to the null value in first name.

you just have put a null check on each field and u r good to go.

you can generate the inv_number on the time of bulk uploading also by adding null check in the same code on and placing the code on Add> On Submt.( just the part inside the loop )

the **Better** option would be using a formula field, you just have to put this formula in that formula field and you'll get your inventory_number autogenerated , you can rename the formula_field to Inv Number or whaterver u want.

Since you are using substring directly in year Field, I am assuming the
 year field as string.else you would have to user Year.tostring().substring(2,4) & instead of if(Year=="","",...) you have to put if(Year==null , null,...);

so here's the formula

```
    if(First_Name=="","",First_Name.subString(0,1))+if(Last_Name =="","",Last_Name.subString(0,1)) + if(Year=="","",Year.subString(2,4)+Number
```

Let me know ur response if u implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the datatype its difficult to fix, but making the assumption that your `Inventory_Record.number` is a numeric data item you are adding a string to a number:

The "+" is used for string Concatenation - Joiner but it also adds two numbers together so think `"a" + "b" = "ab"` for strings but for numbers `1 + 2 = 3`.

All good, but when you do `"a" + 2` the system doesn't know whether to add or concatenate so gives an error.